# how to check if there is a value in mysql row?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, image

sorry for my english

i want to ask how to check if there is a value in the row or not ?

thanks in advance :)

```
Private Sub uploadpic()

    Dim SQLCmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Picture FROM Student_information WHERE S_I_D = ('" & ListView1.Items(ListView1.FocusedItem.Index).SubItems(0).Text & "') ", dbcon)

    dbcon.Open()

    *Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())*

    dbcon.Close()

    Dim picture As Image = Nothing

    'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.

    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
        'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.
        PictureBox4.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
    End Using


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executescalar) will return a null reference if the result set is empty. So you can check that value to know whether there is a value in the row or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim sql As string("SELECT Picture FROM Student_information WHERE S_I_D = ('{0}')",ListView1.Items(ListView1.FocusedItem.Index).SubItems(0).Text)
    tbl = GetRecords(sql)
        If tbl.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            'Code to execute
        Else
        exit sub 'or msgbox "record not found"
        End If 

Public Function GetRecords(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable
    Return GetRecordsExtracted(sql)
End Function

Private Function GetRecordsExtracted(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    tbl = New DataTable
    da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, dbcon.Open)
    da.Fill(tbl)
    Return tbl
End Function
```